# How to export an edited clip into a video file in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, file-format

I am in the video sequence editor, cut out fragments, combined the remaining into one whole new clip and do not know how to procede from here on in order to obtain a video file (h264, mpeg4).

I tried to click the animation button and all I got was a some pictures I already had cut out.

Comment: Could you post your output file format settings you can find in the Render tab?

Answer (score 12):

I will try to answer your question. I will be my first answer so bare with me ;-) See the attached image. Specify the render preset (such as the HDTV 720p or some other). Specify frames per second. Enable Sequencer in the Post Processing tab (this will switch render mode from 3D rendering to video sequence rendering). And in the output tab choose H.264 (it will be MPG4 by default as I recall). Also specify an output path and filename. And hit Animation.

[image]

Comment: don't forget the encoding tab, here you can choose AVI, quicktime and other formats and codecs. If you have audio you can choose the audio codec also in the encoding tab

Comment: and also on the Post Processing section enable **Sequencer**

Comment: Ok, but.... where is this window in the first place?

Comment: @DanielMöller The _`Current editor type for this aria`_ should be `Properties` to access these options (upper-left corner of screen-shot), also it may help to switch the _`Engine to use for rendering`_ to `Cycles`; near the top-center of Blender window.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant anymore. The renderer tab has properties like "Render Engine", Sampling, Viewport, Bloom, etc… But no "animation" button. It is worth noting though that the GUI looks completely different compared to this answer, I only guessed that I look at the correct window because I found the other menus there, like "Output name", "Sequencer", "Post-processing", etc. Blender version is `2.92.0` here. Apparently they completely redesigned that part.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "Animation" and on the bottom right and scroll to output the the file logo is change the destination. Then below that there should be a little thing that says "PNG". Change that to "FFMPEG". After that go down to "Encoding" and open the tab and scroll down to the very bottom and beside "audio co" where it says "none" change it to what ever you want it to be. lastly render it using the movie icon button.

Comment: Pointing out where exactly that "Animation" is could help. I see no such text anywhere on Blender 2.92.0, I suppose it was hidden somewhere in menus.