# How to save cut video as a video file in Blender 2.92.0

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, file-format, saving

As the title says. This is similar to [this answered question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38676/how-to-export-an-edited-clip-into-a-video-file-in-the-vse), but before marking it as a duplicate please note there's a problem with that post: it is outdated.

Basically, all existing answers that I found on various sites refer to pressing some `Animate` button as a way of triggering the process of saving to a file, and the button has disappeared. On the current interface the most similar one I found is `Render → Render Animation` at the top menu, but all it does is creating a new window with a playback, which has no obvious way of finally triggering the save to a file *(and I also found a `Sequence Render Animation` menu elsewhere, which seems to do the same thing)*.

I've been searching for about two hours already, and I'm kind of becoming desperate at this point. I find amusing that Blender [even has a documentation about setting up a video output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/output/video.html), but it lacks the most crucial step: how to make those properties result in an actual video file.

For reference, below is a screenshot of the current interface.

[image: Blender 2.92.0 GUI]

At the top-right half of the window you can see a panel with video output settings: a codec, a quality, and most importantly there's an output directory. But whatever I do in the program, the output directory is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! Turns out, it is the menu <kbd>Render</kbd> → <kbd>Render Animation</kbd>: it makes a window pop up, and after that window finishes playing, a video file appears.

But as I mentioned, I tried that menu and it didn't work, right? So why wasn't I finding it? Well, turns out when you set up the output directory for a file, you **must** end it with a slash. Otherwise the last `/`-separated chunk of the text would be interpreted as part of a resulting filename. Which means that if I wrote a path `/tmp/foo` *(expecting the file to end up in the `/tmp/foo` directory that I created)*, then it saves to a file like `/tmp/foo-SOME-POSTFIX.mkv`, and I had too much stuff in my `/tmp` directory, so I simply missed it.